# How do I visualize single values in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I'd like to visualize single values together with classical charts in plotly. In the end I'd like to have some kind of dashboard showing charts and these single values (three values).

Is there some possibility to do that with plotly? I'm happy if the single value look a little bit fancy but it is not essential. I'm also happy about an alternative method to combine plotly charts with some other possibility of visualizing single values.

Thank you :)

Comment: so what did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Thomas I used Google to see if I can find plotly visualization for single values but I could not find any. I just read somewhere (cant remember where) that it is possible I just dont know how. So thats why I ask here.

Comment: could you provide some kind of example? is not clear what you want

Comment: @vlizana jea I think I can. Lets say I have a single value "Visitors in the last 24h" which is 35295 then I'd like to present it somehow like here: https://agencyanalytics.com/assets/feature/screenshot/dashboard.png (Note that this is not my dashboard). I know that this kind of vsiualization is quite easy using Splunk but I don't have splunk for this project available :)

Comment: @pinas this is not a `give me the solution` forum, this is a I'm having problem with this code forum. So where is your effort?

Comment: @Thomas I was hoping for a "this is the standard way you visualize single values in plotly now go and figure out how to write this as code" answer.

Comment: I don't know of a standard way to do this, as you can see in the example dashboard there is some additional information other than the single value. It looks to me like an [annotated](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/) pie chart.

Comment: You could use a plot with multiple subplots for the graphs and for the single values add `annotation`s.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your tips. For now I used the probably easiest and least fancy method - I created a 1x1 table and put the single value into it, in code this looks like this:

```
table_single_bpract = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['<b>Best Practice Violation</b>'],
                line=dict(color='#7D7F80'),
                fill=dict(color='#a1c3d1'),
                align=['left'] * 5,
                font=dict(size=25, color='#7f7f7f')),
    cells=dict(values=[["<b>Score: "+str(sample_bpract)+"</b>", "<b>Diff. to Avg.: "+str(bpract_diff)+"</b>"]],
               line=dict(color='#7D7F80'),
               fill=dict(color='#EDFAFF'),
               align=['left'] * 5,
                font = dict(size=25, color='#7f7f7f')),
    domain = dict(x=[0.70, 1], y=[0.8, 1]),
)
```

I'll need to beautify it a bit in the next sprint then I'll try the recommendations regarding annotated graphs. I'm still a little bit dissapointed that plotly is not offering default to represent some single values (e.g., like a meter or the classic traffic light) but it is probably not meant for this :)

Thx again!